# Magento Transaction Email Variables - Get Postcode

Tags: magento, transactional-email

Need to include the Shipping Postcode for a DPD tracking link to work, but cannot find the a way to insert only the Shipping Postcode/Zipcode.

Any help inserting just the shipping postcode would be very helpful, I assume something like this:

{{var order.shippingPostcode}}

Many thanks

Comment: I have now found a suitable solution for this. For those looking to solve the same problem, I modified the "Text One Line" Address template found in Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Address Templates to have only postcode, then called it in the transaction email using: {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('oneline')}}

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getPostcode()}}
```

in your transactional template as a placeholder for the postcode.